# how to filter and add the remaining obj in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to modify particular object in Javascript,

I am able to get the obj based on filter but how to add ``` 'in'='bank'  and 'out'='bank' of nonfiltered id to the end of filtered obj

`'bank'` should be default if `in` and `out` is `'bank'`,
`in` is `'credit'` and `out` is `'bank'` and `id` is `'trans'`, then filter the `'trans'` and add the remaining `in`, `out`, `bank` and `ids`as shown.

```
function getValue(send,receive, id){
 const temp = obj.map(e => Object.entries(e).map(([k, val]) => val)).flat(3)
    this.selectedProviderList = temp.filter(x=>x.in== send && x.in ==receive && x.id==id);
}

getValue("credit", "bank", "trans");
```

```
var obj = [{
    "btob": [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }],
    "ctob": [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 20
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }]
}]
```

For example, get the values if `in` is `'credit'` and `out` is `'bank'` and `id` is `'trans'`.

```
// Expected Output
[
   {
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 20
    },
    {
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }
]

// get the values if 'in' is 'debit' and 'out' is 'bank' and id is "fund" 

[{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "debit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }]

// get the values if 'in' is 'bank' and 'out' is bank and id is "trans"

  [{
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    },{
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }]
```

Comment: In your expected output, why is the `"id": "fund", "in": "bank"` included in your array when your criteria is `in is 'credit' and out is 'bank' and id is 'trans'.`?

Comment: @Himanshu Shekha thanks for prompt reply, but need to  filter the value and add the in ="bank" and "out"="bank" of  non filtered value to array object(considering default)

Comment: @CloudSohJunFu thanks for reply, I have to filter based on condition the ``` in is 'credit' and out is 'bank' and id is 'trans'```, add the non-filtered obj  ```in ="bank" and out "bank" of id to filterobj```

Comment: @Himanshu Shekha am able to get the filtered value from the code what i have tired but how to add the non filtered obj considering ``` in =="bank"  and out=="bank "

Comment: @sowmiya , So , if the object which do not fit  in getValue(param1,param2,param3). Then we should modify that object in and out with the bank. Am I right?

Comment: @Himanshu Shekha no, should not modify, should add to the end of filtered obj     
 ``` [
   {
      "id": "trans",
      "in": "credit",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 20
    },
    {
      "id": "fund",
      "in": "bank",
      "out": "bank",
      "value": 10
    }
] ```

Comment: Your question is not the problem, the problem is that we can't understand your question. Try to explain it in better ways.

Answer (score 3):

if you able to convert your obj then one step filter can do this

```js
var obj = [
        {
          "id": "trans",
          "in": "bank",
          "out": "bank",
          "value": 10
        },
        {
          "id": "fund",
          "in": "bank",
          "out": "bank",
          "value": 10
        },
       {
          "id": "trans",
          "in": "credit",
          "out": "bank",
          "value": 20
        },
        {
          "id": "fund",
          "in": "credit",
          "out": "bank",
          "value": 10
        }
    ]
// get the values if in is 'credit' and out is 'bank' and  id is 'trans'
 let resOne=obj.filter((givenObj)=>{
if(givenObj.in=="credit"&&givenObj.out=="bank"&&givenObj.id == "trans"){
  return givenObj
}
 })
  console.log(resOne)
 
 
 //// get the values if 'in' is 'debit' and 'out' is 'bank' and id is "fund" 
  let resTwo=obj.filter((givenObj)=>{
if(givenObj.in=="debit"&&givenObj.out=="bank"&&givenObj.id == "fund"){
  return givenObj
}
 })
   console.log(resTwo)
   
   
   //// get the values if 'in' is 'bank' and 'out' is bank and id is "trans"
    let resThree=obj.filter((givenObj)=>{
if(givenObj.in=="bank"&&givenObj.out=="bank"&&givenObj.id == "trans"){
  return givenObj
}
 })
   console.log(resThree)
```

Answer (score 0):

TYpo error x.id==id instead of x.id = id and recieve in param but in filter is receive

```
 function getValue(send,recieve, id){
  const temp = obj.map(e => Object.entries(e).map(([k, val]) => val)).flat(3)
   this.selectedProviderList = temp.filter(x=>x.in== send && x.in == recieve && 
   x.id==id);
 }

getValue("credit", "bank", "trans");
```